# what is the bind event to detect change in value from daterangepicker?

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-grid, daterangepicker

When selecting a date or date range from a daterangepicker, I want the kendo ui grid to apply my custom  date filtering. When typing or pasting dates, the filtering works. However, if the date is chosen from a daterangepicker, no event is fired to make the ajax filtering call.

I tried click event, but the ajax call is made after selecting the date and then going back to the filter text box and clicking on it.

Desired functionality would be to click and pick a date from the daterangepicker and that click would filter.

```
    grid.find(".custom-filter").bind("click", function (){

                gridData.dataSource.filter(getFilteredGrid(grid));

    });
```

Any suggestions on solving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there an event called "OnSelectionChanged" that you can over ride?

Comment: that didn't fire anything. Thanks for the reply.